# Get decoded / non html from Ajax HtmlEditor

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, ajax, html-editor

I am struggling to retrieve content as plain text from the AJAX `HtmlEditor`.

I am using `editor.get_content()` to retrieve the content and I am needing it to be in plain text so that I can compare to the initial value of the content. This needs to be done client side in Javascript.

For example the plain text I require is along the lines of -

```
<a href='blah' ....
```

What I'm getting out is:

```
<a shape="rect" href="blah".....
```

I cannot use the following answer as i am unable to specify a static `iframe`. Unless there is a way to dynamicly retieve it?

[How to get value (non html) from ajax html editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270636)

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

http://htmleditor.codeplex.com/

Its works fine for me.